# Pandas group by column and add numbered rows to each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data stored in a pandas.DataFrame object named `df`. The column `id` is a unique identifier and the remaining columns are irrelevant for the purpose of this question.

|  | id | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01001 | 523.41 | 639673 | 1222.13 |
| 1 | 01002 | 54.832 | 33746 | 615.443 |
| 2 | 01003 | 48.3824 | 45196 | 934.142 |

I want to know if there's a way to group by `id` and use `assign` to add multiple numbered rows to each group.

In other words, I want to use `range` to add an arbitrary number of rows to each `id`. The desired result looks as follows:

|  | id | x1 | x2 | x3 | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01001 | 523.41 | 639673 | 1222.13 | 2020 |
| 0 | 01001 | 523.41 | 639673 | 1222.13 | 2021 |
| 1 | 01002 | 54.832 | 33746 | 615.443 | 2020 |
| 1 | 01002 | 54.832 | 33746 | 615.443 | 2021 |
| 2 | 01003 | 48.3824 | 45196 | 934.142 | 2020 |
| 2 | 01003 | 48.3824 | 45196 | 934.142 | 2021 |

I was hoping something along these lines would work.

```py
df = df.groupby('id').assign(new_col=range(2020, 2022))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat the index and use `numpy.tile` to tile the new data:

```py
import numpy as np

new = ['2020', '2021']

df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(new))]
df2['new_col'] = np.tile(new, len(df))
```

Output:

```
     id        x1      x2        x3 new_col
0  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130    2020
0  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130    2021
1  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443    2020
1  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443    2021
2  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142    2020
2  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142    2021
```

Alternatively:

```py
new = range(2020, 2022)
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(new))]
df2['new_col'] = new.start + df2.groupby('id').cumcount()
```

Comment: I added an alternative solution based on `df.index.repeat`. It's very similar to your solution, but it is slightly closer to what I originally had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

We can also create a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.reindex.html) relative to `level=0`, to scale up the DataFrame, and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert the inner level of the MultiIndex into a column:

```py
df = df.reindex(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df.index, range(2020, 2022)],
        names=[None, 'new_col']
    ),
    level=0
).reset_index(level='new_col')
```

`df`:

```
   new_col    id        x1      x2        x3
0     2020  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130
0     2021  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130
1     2020  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443
1     2021  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443
2     2020  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142
2     2021  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142
```

We can reorder `new_col` to the end if needed:

```py
df = df.reindex(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df.index, range(2020, 2022)],
        names=[None, 'new_col']
    ),
    level=0
).reset_index(level='new_col')

# Re-order columns
df = df.reindex(
    columns=df.columns[df.columns != 'new_col'].union(['new_col'], sort=False)
)
```

`df`:

```
     id        x1      x2        x3  new_col
0  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130     2020
0  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130     2021
1  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443     2020
1  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443     2021
2  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142     2020
2  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142     2021
```

---

Setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1001, 1002, 1003],
    'x1': [523.41, 54.832, 48.3824],
    'x2': [639673, 33746, 45196],
    'x3': [1222.13, 615.443, 934.142]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(pd.Series(range(2020, 2022),name='col1'),how='cross')

    id        x1      x2        x3  col1
0  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130  2020
1  1001  523.4100  639673  1222.130  2021
2  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443  2020
3  1002   54.8320   33746   615.443  2021
4  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142  2020
5  1003   48.3824   45196   934.142  2021
```